# (Kotlin) How to save hashmap output to file

Tags: java, kotlin, hashmap

I am having trouble writing the contents of my hashmap to a file when I select the option. I have successfully read from a file, and utilized various functions to adjust my catalog of products. However, every time I choose my save option. The file clear minus 1 of the products.

Thank you. I appreciate any help in regards to solving this issue.

Comment: It seems you try to close the file after each written line. Did you try the `fd.close()` function after the write loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the file printer after writing all the records to the file.

Move `fd.close()` out of the for-loop.

```
for (record in products) {
    fd.println("${record.key},${record.value.first},${record.value.second}")
    // fd.close() << from here
}
fd.close() // to here
```